# Normalizing forces for basketball game

Tags: java, algorithm, game, coordinate-system, libgdx

Recently I found the need to implement a normalization formula in a couple of places in my basketball game, so I created some static methods inside of a class to do so.

```
public class Normalize {

    //explanation of normalization formula:
    /*
    Suppose you have a range or scale from A to B and you want to convert 
    it to a scale of 1 to 10, where A maps to 1 and B maps to 10.  
    Furthermore, we want to do this with a linear function, so that for 
    example the point midway between A and B maps to halfway between 1 and 
    10, or 5.5.

    Then the following (linear) equation can be applied to any number 
    x on the A-B scale:
    */  
    //y = 1 + (x-A)*(10-1)/(B-A)

    public static Vector2 normalizedVector(Vector2 velocity, float min, float max, float normalizedMin, float normalizedMax) {
        float inputX = velocity.x;
        float inputY = velocity.y;
        float normalizedX = normalizedMin + (inputX-min) * (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max-min);
        float normalizedY = normalizedMin + (inputY-min) * (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max-min);
        return new Vector2(normalizedX, normalizedY);
    }

    public static float normalizedStrength (Vector2 velocity, float min, float max, float normalizedMin, float normalizedMax) {
        float inputX = velocity.x;
        float inputY = velocity.y;
        float inputTotal = inputX + inputY;
        return normalizedMin + (inputTotal-min) * (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max-min);
    }
}
```

I use this code in a couple of places in the game.  First, I'm using it to reduce the strength of the impact force of a ball when it hits the hoop, in order to make sure that it does not move too far as a result of the collision:

```
public void ballCollided(float angle, Vector2 velocity) {

    //the angle is not currently used in the calculation

    //the 0 and 100 are hard coded here
    //the value represents the power of the ball velocity
    //that i got from shooting balls at max power
    //usually the value was 88 to 95 ish
    //if the ball was moving at much higher speeds or something this would need to change
    float min = 0;
    float max = 100;
    Vector2 normalizedVector = Normalize.normalizedVector(velocity, min, max, this.normalizedMinPower, this.normalizedMaxPower);
    this.amountToMoveForBallHitX += normalizedVector.x;
    this.amountToMoveForBallHitY += normalizedVector.y;
}
```

In anther place, I am using it to determine the amount to shake the screen when the ball collides with the hoop, as well as to determine the correct sound effect to play:

```
public void ballHitHoop(Vector2 velocity) {
    //these values observed from watching the logs of ball strength
    float min = 0;
    float max = 100f;

    //these values affect how much it shakes
    float minPower = 0;
    float maxPower = 1f;

    float shakeTime = 40;

    float power = Normalize.normalizedStrength(velocity, min, max, minPower, maxPower);
    this.screenShake.rumble(power, shakeTime, this.camCenterX, this.camCenterY);

    this.playThumpForPower(power);
}
```

Is there a more efficient or more readable way to accomplish this?

Edit: As requested, here is an example test. Much more complicated tests are possible, but this test just shows normalizing 0 to 100 to be between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
@Test
public void normalizeToBetween0And1() {
    Vector2 strength100a = new Vector2(50, 50);
    Vector2 strength100b = new Vector2(100, 0);
    Vector2 strength50a = new Vector2(25, 25);
    Vector2 strength50b = new Vector2(20, 30);
    Vector2 strength20a = new Vector2(10, 10);
    Vector2 strength20b = new Vector2(11, 9);

    //origin values will be between 0 and 100
    float min = 0;
    float max = 100;

    //target values are between 0.0 and 1.0
    float normalizedMin = 0;
    float normalizedMax = 1;

    float normalized100a = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength100a, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized100a);
    assertEquals(normalized100a, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    float normalized100b = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength100b, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized100b);
    assertEquals(normalized100b, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    float normalized50a = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength50a, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized50a);
    assertEquals(normalized50a, 0.5f, 0.0f);

    float normalized50b = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength50b, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized50b);
    assertEquals(normalized50b, 0.5f, 0.0f);

    float normalized20a = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength20a, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized20a);
    assertEquals(normalized20a, 0.2f, 0.0f);

    float normalized20b = Normalize.normalizedStrength(strength20b, min, max, normalizedMin, normalizedMax);
    System.out.println(normalized20b);
    assertEquals(normalized20b, 0.2f, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: _Better_ by which exact means please?

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: Not of a great clarification though :-( ...

Comment: Not sure what else you are looking for?

Comment: How are you using these methods in your code? I'm a bit confused by the `normalizedStrength` method

Comment: Do you have some example inputs or test cases?

Comment: Where do those parameters come from? Do `min`, `max`, `normalizedMin`, and `normalizedMax` change frequently? I would guess that if you call these functions many times, then you would be redoing many of the calculations.

Comment: The parameters are based on values coming from the physics world. No they do not change frequently, but the values are stored in other classes which pass them into these static methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just some small tips with regards to this simple code.

Avoid duplication like this:

> ```
> float normalizedX = normalizedMin + (inputX-min) * (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max-min);
> float normalizedY = normalizedMin + (inputY-min) * (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max-min);
> ```

I re-read 3 times these long statements to make sure that the expression at the right are identical. If you put that in a local variable, then:

- it will be easier to read, since it will be obvious that the expressions are the same
- it will be easier to read without scrolling to the right
- it will be easier to modify, in case you need to, as you can change in one place

Look, now the piece of code fits within the page here too:

```
float coef = (normalizedMax - normalizedMin) / (max - min);
float normalizedX = normalizedMin + (inputX-min) * coef;
float normalizedY = normalizedMin + (inputY-min) * coef;
```